# How to create wordpress multi drop-down category search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, themes

I have created two drop down category list . One of that is Main Category and another is Sub Category. If I select one from Main category then show sub category automatically but I want when I select one subcategory , its  all post load automatically to archive page. so what should I do? How can do it?

Comment: Maybe put some code into your question to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ajax.

You need to create a function that receives the category/subcategory and does a WP_Query based in that, then returns a list of the post.

To make the ajax call I sugest using the `$.get();`

For example:

```
var data = {
   category : you_category;
};

$.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
   ... update the list of posts
});
```